# Nesting entity of the same type in collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I wonder if example below makes any sense. I'm using Entity Framework 6.
Suppose we have Enitity:

```
public class Bike
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public Guid ParentBikeId { get; set; }

   public virtual Bike ChildBike { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Bike> ParentedBikes { get; set; }
}
```

and inside my `OnModelCreating` I add:

```
builder
  .HasOne(x => x.ChildBike)
  .WithMany(x => x.ParentedBikes)
  .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentBikeId);
```

I tried to use that, but on migrations EF throws me an error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'RecruitmentStages'
```

Comment: What is a "RecruitmentStages"? You might also want to have `ParentBikeId` nullable if there are bikes that don't have parents.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is just an entity I'm originally working on. The Bike is just an example. What do you think? The nesting in this example is correct?

Comment: EF6 doesn't have a `HasOne` method. Are you sure you're using EF6, and not .NET 6.0 with EF Core?